# User Name and Password Generator

Tags: c++, qt

Please help.

Here is the question: Write a Qt Graphical User Interface (GUI) program to generate a username and an initial password given
the full name of the user.

Given below are the rules for generating a valid username:

- It consists of 5 characters, where the first character is in upper case and the rest of the four
  characters are in smaller case.
- The user name is created by combining the first 4 characters of the surname with the first character of
  the first name.
- If the surname does not have 4 characters, more characters are taken from the first name to make up
  the user name.
- If the surname and the first name combined is less than 5 characters then append sufficient number
  of 0s to create the username.
- An initial password is generated by combining randomly selected 5 characters from the full name of the
  user.
- Note than no spaces are allowed in the username or password.
- User input should be obtained using a QInputDialog.
- You can expect the full name as a single string, where each word is separated using a space. For example: Mike William Owen.
- The output (username and password) should be displayed using a QMessageBox.
- You need not do any verification of the user input.

When I run the program, the password doesn't reflect 5 random characters - only the same character - which differs every time you run the program.I also cannot figure out how to include the 4th rule.

Any help would be appreciated

Here is the code:

```
#include <QtGui>  
#include <QDebug>  

int randInt(int low, int high)
{  
    QTime time = QTime::currentTime(); qsrand((uint)time.msec());  
    return qrand() % ((high + 1) - low) + low;  
}  

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QString userFullName = QInputDialog::getText(0, "User Full Name", "Enter your name and surname (first name last name)");  
    QStringList userInfo = userFullName.split(" ");  
    QString password;

    QString firstName = userInfo[0].trimmed();  
    QString lastName = userInfo[1].trimmed();

    QString FullName = firstName.toLower() + lastName.toLower();  

    if (FullName.size() < 5)  
    {
        FullName.insert(4,"0");  
    }

    int userL = FullName.length();   

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int num = randInt(0,userL);  
        password[i] = FullName[num];  
    }

    if(userInfo.size() >= 2)
    {
        QString lastNameChars;  
        QString firstNameChars;  

        if (lastName.size() >= 4)  
        {
            QString firstL = QString(lastName.at(0));  
            firstL.toUpper();  
            QString secondL = QString(lastName.at(1));  
            secondL.toLower();  
            QString thirdL = QString(lastName.at(2));  
            thirdL.toLower();  
            QString fourthL = QString(lastName.at(3));  
            fourthL.toLower();  
            lastNameChars = firstL + secondL + thirdL + fourthL;  
            firstNameChars = QString(firstName.at(0));  
        }
        else if (lastName.size() == 3)  
        {
            QString firstL = QString(lastName.at(0));  
            firstL.toUpper();  
            QString secondL = QString(lastName.at(1));  
            secondL.toLower();  
            QString thirdL = QString(lastName.at(2));  
            thirdL.toLower();  
            lastNameChars = firstL + secondL + thirdL;  
            firstNameChars = QString(firstName.at(0)) +   
            QString(firstName.at(1));
        }
        else if (lastName.size() == 2 )  
        {
            QString firstL = QString(lastName.at(0));  
            firstL.toUpper();  
            QString secondL = QString(lastName.at(1));  
            secondL.toLower();  
            lastNameChars = firstL + secondL;  
            firstNameChars = QString(firstName.at(0)) + QString(firstName.at(1)) + QString(firstName.at(2));
        }
        else if (lastName.size() == 1 )
        {
            QString firstL = QString(lastName.at(0));  
            firstL.toUpper();  
            lastNameChars = firstL;  
            firstNameChars = QString(firstName.at(0)) + QString(firstName.at(1)) + QString(firstName.at(2)) + QString(firstName.at(3));
        }

        QString UserName = lastNameChars + firstNameChars.toLower();

        QString response = QString("The password is %1 for %2 %3 and the  username is %4 and the full name is %5").arg(password).arg(firstName).arg(lastName).arg(UserName).arg(FullName);
        QMessageBox::information(0, "Results", response);   
    }
    else
    {
        QMessageBox::information(0, "Error", "Incorrect input data");
    }

    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call srand (or qsrand in this case) only once at the beginning of the program. Otherwise you don't get random numbers.

```
//remove qsrand from randInt(), put in main
qsrand(QTime::currentTime().msec());

int userL = FullName.length();
if (userL < 5)
{
    for (int i = userL; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int n = randInt('a', 'z');
        QString buf;
        buf.sprintf("%c", n);
        FullName += buf;
    }
}
```